# Interpreting vmstat output

Tags: linux, oracle, jboss, rhel

I was running a load test on a jboss based application. The server has around 8 instances of jboss and oracle enterprise DB (11g) as well. I got the vmstat output like below

[image: VMstat output]

Please help to know what are the problems that I facing with the server?

A few observation that I could make are:

1. A lot of si and so. In top, I could see that there is hardly any memory left.
   2, Why there are so many cpu waits, r, b
2. is the server really overloaded? the cpu user(us) load is not high for most of the lines.

Pls suggest how to interpret this data and look for specific actions to progress.

Answer (score 0):

When ever server uses if its swap every thing goes slow.becauser pages should read from disk and then send to cpu.i thinks you resolve swapping problem because it kills server.